# Update redshift column value with modified data from other column

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table which is used for tracking, and as a result its pretty huge. I need to update one column after applying some text operations and extracting a value from another column.

The query that I have managed to write works only for one row.

```
UPDATE schema.table_name SET data_id = (SELECT split_part(regexp_substr(data_column,'pattern=[^&]*'),'=',2)::BIGINT FROM schema.table_name where id = 1620) WHERE id = 1620;
```

How do I get it to work for every row in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  schema.table_name
SET
  data_id = SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(data_column, 'pattern=[^&]*'),'=',2)::BIGINT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put `WHERE id = 1620;` at end of update query.

Answer (score 0):

Updates are not efficient in Redshift. If you have a huge table and you intend to update every single row, you should instead copy the data (with the updated column) to a new table and then flip them.

Comment: It worked for me. And it was fast. For the record, the table is huge, out of which a million records were updated. I had read in a couple of places that the updates in redshift are "prohibitively slow", and as a result I was hesitant. But it worked.